STM32-F103 Blue Pill Frequency Counter code's frequency triggered output not working
Background:
Essentially, I took a frequency counter code from "Deep Blue Embedded", with the intent of making the program set an output pin high when the frequency dropped to 200 hz or below. Here's the tutorial I used:
https://deepbluembedded.com/stm32-input-capture-frequency-measurement-example-timer-input-capture-mode/
This is my first time using this chip, and I'm using it for a Senior Project in Electronics Engineering. All i need this guy to do is read an RPM from a Tachometer, and when the RPM drops below a certain point, it sends out a Pulse that triggers a relay down the line so it fufills the sensor driven response requirement.
The electronics behind that relay switching I know how to do, but I'm normally an analog guy, I'm not very experienced in programming.
I plugged the output pin PB14 to an Oscope, and the oscope is not showing what i want. I'm looking to have it just go high and stay there to trigger said relay.
What I Did
O-Scope screenshot of the signal coming out of PB14
The pin has been exhibiting that behavior on pretty much every frequency. I've tried 100 hz to 500 hz and it just doesn't seem to be affected by an frequency i need. The motor it's reading an RPM off of is at most gonna get up to 1500 RPM (has a flywheel) so the frequency in the final build is gonna be even lower.
I left in the UART code and configurations in for now since that's what was in the tutorial, and I don't break the code too much. I don't have a UART available, so i'm leaving it there until i have to remove it.
If the UART code not having a hardware to talk to is making the system not work, then help on how to remove the UART functionality without breaking the program would be appreciated.
Here's the code. Tried PAO initially, that didn't work either.
#include "main.h"

#define IDLE   0
#define DONE   1
#define F_CLK  72000000UL

volatile uint8_t gu8_State = IDLE;
volatile uint8_t gu8_MSG[35] = {'\0'};
volatile uint32_t gu32_T1 = 0;
volatile uint32_t gu32_T2 = 0;
volatile uint32_t gu32_Ticks = 0;
volatile uint16_t gu16_TIM2_OVC = 0;
volatile uint32_t gu32_Freq = 0;

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim2;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void);
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);

int main(void)
{
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_TIM2_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim2);
    HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

    while (1)
    {
        //Boosting Frequency Hit
        if(gu32_Freq <= 200)
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_SET);

        //Bucking Frequency Hit
        if(gu32_Freq > 200)
            HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_8, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
}

void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
    if(gu8_State == IDLE)
    {
        gu32_T1 = TIM2->CCR1;
        gu16_TIM2_OVC = 0;
        gu8_State = DONE;
    }
    else if(gu8_State == DONE)
    {
        gu32_T2 = TIM2->CCR1;
        gu32_Ticks = (gu32_T2 + (gu16_TIM2_OVC * 65536)) - gu32_T1;
        gu32_Freq = (uint32_t)(F_CLK/gu32_Ticks);
        if(gu32_Freq != 0)
        {
          sprintf(gu8_MSG, "Frequency = %lu Hz\n\r", gu32_Freq);
          HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1, gu8_MSG, sizeof(gu8_MSG), 100);
        }
        gu8_State = IDLE;
    }
}

void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef* htim)
{
    gu16_TIM2_OVC++;
}
/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};

  /** Initializes the RCC Oscillators according to the specified parameters
  * in the RCC_OscInitTypeDef structure.
  */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEState = RCC_HSE_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSEPredivValue = RCC_HSE_PREDIV_DIV1;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSE;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLL_MUL9;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB buses clocks
  */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

/**
  * @brief TIM2 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 0 */

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 1 */
  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 0;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim2.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim2, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM2_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END TIM2_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief USART1 Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 1 */
  huart1.Instance = USART1;
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart1.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart1.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart1.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart1.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart1.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart1.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN USART1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END USART1_Init 2 */

}

/**
  * @brief GPIO Initialization Function
  * @param None
  * @retval None
  */
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_1 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_1 */

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOD_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

/* USER CODE BEGIN MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
/* USER CODE END MX_GPIO_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @retval None
  */
void Error_Handler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  __disable_irq();
  while (1)
  {
  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t *file, uint32_t line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     ex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */


This is my first time using this chip, and I'm using it for a Senior Project in Electronics Engineering. [...] but I'm normally an analog guy, I'm not very experienced in programming. If you are "an analog guy", why do you then do a program as a Senior Project? Its not something you learn through a question at StackOverflow. I plugged the output pin PB14 to an Oscope, and the oscope is not showing what i want. I don't see why the program you've posted would do anything on PB14. Your main() appears to try to toggle PA8, although I don't know where do you set up that pin either.
